# GitHub oauth doesn't fetch email with scope set to "user:email,read:user"

Tags: spring, authentication, oauth-2.0, github-oauth

I was following [this](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-security-oauth2-social-login-part-1/) tutorial to implement authorization with github using Spring. Here is oauth2 configuration:

```
github:
    clientId: ${GITHUB_CLIENT_ID}
    clientSecret: ${GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}
    redirectUri: "{baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}"
    scope:
       - read:user
       - user:email
```

To fetch profile data app sends request to `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize` with following [parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6zco.png):

- response_type: code
- scope: read:user user:email
- client_id: <client_id>
- state:
- redirect_url:

The problem is that github fetches only public data (as though it ignores scope "user:email")